# What is the Best Practice for manipulating and storing dates in Java?

Tags: java, date

What is the best practice for manipulating and storing Dates e.g. using GregorianCalendar in an enterprise java application?

Looking for feedback and I will consolidate any great answers into a best practice that others can use.

Comment: bla bla bla, joda time, bla bla bla...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Best Practice for Date Manipulation/Storage for Geographically Diverse Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075780/java-best-practice-for-date-manipulation-storage-for-geographically-diverse-user)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is the way to go. Why ?

1. it has a much more powerful and intuitive interface than the standard Date/Time API
2. there are no threading issues with date/time formatting. java.text.SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe (not a lot of people know this!)

At some stage the Java Date/Time API is going to be superseded (by JSR-310). I believe this is going to be based upon the work done by those behind Joda, and as such you'll be learning an API that will influence a new standard Java API.

Comment: Now if you can't use Joda (some projects are limited in what external JARs they can introduce to the project), is using java.util.GregorianCalendar to hold and manipulate dates (making sure you account for DST by doing something like maintaining your dates in UTC timezone) the best practice?

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: Really? I did not know that. Thx for the heads up

Comment: I don't think that add heavy 3rd-party library to the project could be named as best practice in any case at all

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевченко The original date-time classes really are *that* bad, so poorly-designed, confusing, and flawed, that Yes, it was indeed best practice for many of us to add Joda-Time jar to any new project. Fortunately now the successor to Joda-Time, the java.time classes, are built into Java 8 and Java 9. For Java 6 & 7, one should add the *ThreeTen-Backport* project’s library. That back-port is further adapted for earlier Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Answer (score 27):

The best practice is usually precisely **NOT** to think in term of heavy date objects but to store a point in time.  This is typically done by storing a value that doesn't suffer from corner cases nor from potential parsing problems.  To do this, people usually store the number of milliseconds (or seconds) elapsed since a fixed point that we call the epoch (1970-01-01).  This is very common and any Java API will always allow you to convert any kind of date to/from the time expressed in ms since the epoch.

That's for storage.  You can also store, for example, the user's preferred timezone, if there's such a need.

Now such a date in milliseconds, like:

```
System.out.println( System.currentTimeMillis() );
1264875453
```

ain't very useful when it's displayed to the end user, that's for granted.

Which is why you use, for example, the example Joda time to convert it to some user-friendly format before displaying it to the end-user.

You asked for best practice, here's my take on it: storing "date" objects in a DB instead of the time in milliseconds is right there with using floating point numbers to represent monetary amounts.

It's usually a huge code smell.

So Joda time in Java is the way to manipulate date, yes.  But is Joda the way to go to *store* dates? **CERTAINLY NOT**.

Answer (score 11):

[Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) (100% interoperable with the JDK)

> Joda-Time provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time classes. The design allows for multiple calendar systems, while still providing a simple API

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 10):

## UTC

Think, work, and store data in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) rather than any time zone. Think of UTC as the *One True Time*, and all other time zones are mere variations. So while coding, forget all about your own time zone. Do your business logic, logging, data storage, and data exchange in UTC. I suggest every programmer keep a second clock on their desk set to UTC.

## java.time

The modern way is the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

The mentioned [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project provided the inspiration for the java.time classes, and the project is now in maintenance mode with the team advising migration to java.time classes.

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

## ISO 8601

When serializing a date-time value to text, use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

For example, a date-time in UTC is `2016-10-17T01:24:35Z` where the `Z` is short for `Zulu` and means UTC. For other [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) the offset of hours and minutes appears at the end such as `2016-01-23T12:34:56+05:30`. The java.time classes extend this standard format to append the name of the time zone (if known) in square brackets, such as `2016-01-23T12:34:56+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]`.

The standard has many other handy formats as well including for [durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), [intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals), [ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Ordinal_dates), and [year-week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates).

## Database

For database storage, use date-time types for date-time values, such as the [SQL standard data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types) which are primarily `DATE`, `TIME`, and `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Let your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) do the heavy lifting. The driver handles the nitty-gritty details about mediating and adapting between the internals of how Java handles the data and how your database handles the data on its side. But be sure to practice with example data to learn the behaviors of your driver and your database. The SQL standard defines very little about date-time handling and so behaviors vary widely, surprisingly so.

If using a JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 and later, you can fetch and store java.time types directly via the `ResultSet::getObject` and `PreparedStatement::setObject` methods.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … );
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant );
```

For older drivers, you will need to fall back to converting through the java.sql types. Look for new conversion methods added to the old classes. For example, [`java.sql.Timestamp.toInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--).

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getTimestamp( … ).toInstant();
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant ) );
```

Use the java.sql types as briefly as possible. They are a badly designed hack, such as `java.sql.Date` masquerading as a date-only value but actually as a subclass of `java.util.Date` it does indeed have a time-of-day set to the `00:00:00` in UTC. And, oh, you are supposed to ignore the fact of that inheritance says the class doc. An ugly mess.

## Example code

Get the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Storing and fetching that `Instant` object to/from a database is shown above.

To generate an ISO 8601 string, merely call `toString`. The java.time classes all use ISO 8601 formats by default for parsing and generating strings of their various date-time values.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

Adjust into any offset-from-UTC by applying a `ZoneOffset` to get an `OffsetDateTime`. Call `toString` to generate a String in ISO 8601 format.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes( 5 , 30 );
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( offset );
```

A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). When you need to see that same moment through the lens of some region’s own [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Going the other direction, you can extract an `Instant` from an `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` by calling `toInstant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

## Formatting

For presentation to the user as strings in formats other than ISO 8601, [search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20DateTimeFormatter&t=osx&ia=web) for use of the `DateTimeFormatter` class.

While you can specify an custom format, usually best to let java.time automatically localize. To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

## Conversion

Best to avoid the legacy date-time types whenever possible. But if working with old code not yet updated for the java.time types, you can convert to/from the java.time types. For details, see the Question, [Convert java.util.Date to what “java.time” type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36639154/642706).

## Use objects

Use objects rather than mere coded primitives and simple strings. For example:

- Do not use 1-7 to represent a day-of-week, use the [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum such as `DayOfWeek.TUESDAY`.
- Rather than passing around a string as a date, pass around [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects.
- Rather than pass around a pair of integers for a year-and-month, pass around [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) objects.
- Instead of 1-12 for a month, use the much more readable [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum such as [`Month.JANUARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#JANUARY).

Using such objects makes your code more self-documenting, ensures valid values, and provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

Answer (score -2):

To get the discussion started, here's been my experience:

When creating standards for a typical 3-tier Java Enterprise project, I would generally recommend that the project use GregorianCalendar for manipulating dates. Reason is GregorianCalendar is the de facto standard over any other Calendar instance e.g. Julian calendar etc. It's the recognized calendar in most countries and properly handles leap years, etc. On top of that, I would recommend that the application store its dates as UTC so that you can easily perform date calculations such as finding the difference between two dates (if it were stored as EST for example, you'd have to take day light savings time into account). The date can be then be localized to whatever timezone you need it to be displayed to the user as -- such as localizing it to EST if you are an east-coast US company and you want your time information shown in EST.

Comment: "e.g. Julian calendar etc"  You can leave this out, since it doesn't make any sense.  There are too many corner cases to start listing things here.  For example, Astronomers use an Astronomical Julian day number.  They also use Gregorian Dates.  Better to say less on this point.  Also, it helps to use bullets for each of your points.

Comment: Why would a 3-tier project differ from any other project?

Comment: FYI, the old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.